# Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Typography error on line 315

Tags: channel, module, error, server, fatal

I'm getting this error on the front-end, although the back-end/CP seems to be working correctly:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Typography::initialize() 
in /my_path/system/expressionengine/modules/channel/mod.channel.php on line 315
```

The server wizard works fine, and 1.x that was running on the same server/directory was functioning as well.

Where should I start to look? Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

Well well, problem solved with simply resetting all permissions to its correct places (even the non-cache/config files), and re-uploading core files.

Feeling silly? YES!